# How do I use a button to add 3 different scores into one textbox?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have one textbox designated for "score" and another for "scores." Along with these two textboxes, I have a button called "add score." The score textbox handles 1 score. Every time I click the add score button, it should add a new score to the scores textbox. For example, if I enter "33" as the first score and click the add score button, then enter "45" and click the add score button, the scores textbox should display "33, 45." I want exactly 3 scores, and the 3 scores to display separately as a string in the scores textbox.

So far the only idea I had was to declare an array.

```
 private void btnAddScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
                string name = txtName.Text;
                int score = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);
                int[] scores = new int[2];                
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to create your array before-hand so that it will be available for use when the button gets clicked. Instead of creating one inside to button handler.

With array you can use to show all the scores in the scores array as a string (comma separated):

```
string newString = string.empty;

foreach(int s in scores)
  {
     int n = 1, slen = scores.length;
     if(n == 1 || n >= slen)
       { separator = ""; }
     else
       { separator = ", ";}
     newString = newString + separator + s.ToString();
     n += 1;
  }
```

Or static:

```
private void btnAddScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
            string name = txtName.Text;
            if(Scores.length <= 3)
            {
              txtScores.Text = txtScores.Text.ToString() + ", " + txtScore.Text.ToString();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you this approach:

```
    private void btnAddScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
            string scores = txtName.Text;
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scores) && scores.Split(',').Count() == 3)
            {
              MessageBox.Show("You can't enter more than three scores");
              return;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(scores))
            {
                scores += txtScore.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                scores += ", " + txtScore.Text;
            }
            txtName.Text = scores;

    }
```